# grails 3.0.4 throws SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Tags: java, grails, ssl, ssl-certificate, grails-3.0

I have downloaded grails 3.0.4 today itself and created a new app. On running grails run-app I get a javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException.

I have performed only two steps.

1. grails create-app demoapp
2. grails run-app

Tried to google the error but could not find much information. I am not behind any proxy. Any idea what could be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Grails site has the certificate expired today (https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9200)

If you're using grails 3.x as you indicated you can change your `build.gradle` file and replace the repository section with

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}
```

replace any https://repo.grails with http if you're using plugins too

Comment: Frederic is correct.  We are actively working on getting the new cert in place now.  I hope it won't be much longer.  Apologies for the disruption.  Frederic, thanks for providing helpful information.